# What is the problem in the Python code below?

Tags: python

The Python code below throws an error.

```
def f(a,*, **c):
    pass
```

The error says that `SyntaxError: named arguments must follow bare *`. I couldn't understand what this means in this case. I have specified a parameter after the bare `*`, yet I get an error.

Comment: The interpret means that you must specify `something` immediately after `*`, not add another argument after `*`.

Comment: * is not an argument. pass something with *

Comment: It's valid to write something like ```def f(a, *, c)```. So the fact that something must follow  immediately after ```*```, is not right, I guess.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  If nothing else, we expect you to look up the error message before posting here.

Comment: `**c` is not, strictly speaking, a named argument, as it represents an arbitrary (and possibly empty) collection of keyword arguments.

Comment: I was certain I saw this question somewhere already, finally found it: https://bugs.python.org/issue2613

Comment: @cglacet You're link was so helpful. Believe me. thanks for it..

Answer (score -1):

A standalone `*` parameter is only necessary (and as you've seen, allowed) if you specify one or more named keyword-only parameters following it. Since you have no named keyword-only parameters, you need to omit it.

```
def f(a, **c):
    pass
```

If you want `a` to be a positional-only argument, you need to use a standalone `/` parameter:

```
def f(a, /, **c):
    pass
```

Comment: I think it's important to note that `f(2, 3)` would raise an error (as I guess the OP expects): `f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`